# Centering <main> content in <body>

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I want to center the content of MAIN horizontally and vertically on the page, but whichever solution I tried, it didn't work. I'm absolutely frustrated atm, because I got it to work, then I changed a lot and it reset itself.

Maybe someone could look over it and give me a hint where I'm wrong. Thank you.

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

/********** LANDINGPAGE.CSS **********/
/**********  **********/
*, header, footer {
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-size: 1vw;
color: #4c4c4c;
letter-spacing: 0.05em;
text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 4vw;
}


/********** SITE **********/
.wrap_site {
max-width: 100%;
margin: 0 5%;
}

.wrap_content {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

.button {
border: 1px solid #4c4c4c;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
font-size: 1vw;
padding: 8px 18px;
background-color: white;
}

.button:hover {
transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
color: white;
background-color: #4c4c4c;
}


/********** HEADER **********/
.wrap_header {
left: 0;
right: 0;
top: 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #4c4c4c;
padding-top: 1rem;
padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

header {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}


/********** FOOTER **********/
.wrap_footer {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: 0 5%;
border-top: 1px solid #4c4c4c;
padding-top: 1rem;
padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

footer {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrap_site">
 <div class="wrap_header">
  <header>
   <p></p> <!-- filler -->
   <p>This website is currently under construction.</p> </header> </div>
      
 <main class="wrap_content">
  <h1>Hi, my name is x. Welcome to my website.</h1>
  <h2 id="translate">你好, 我叫 x。欢迎来到我的网站。</h2>
  </br>
  <h2><a href="#" class="button">ABOUT ME</a></h2> </main>
  
 <div class="wrap_footer">
  <footer>
   <a href="mailto:x">contact@x.com  </a>
   <a href="imprint">⚖️ Imprint</a> </footer> </div> </div>

<!-- AUTOTRANSLATE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-javascript">
jQuery(function ($) {
    var languages = ["¡Hola, me llamo x! Bienvenido a mi página web.", "Привет, меня зовут x. Добро пожаловать на мой сайт.","Hallo, ich heiße x. Willkommen auf meiner Webseite.", "你好, 我叫 x。欢迎来到我的网站。"];
    var counter = 0;
    var $exc = $('#translate')
    setInterval(function () {
        $exc.text(languages[counter++]);
        if (counter >= languages.length) {
            counter = 0;
        }
    }, 2500)
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "center vertically and horizontally"? Maybe a screenshot of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: [Here][1] is the good article about centring anything ;) Horizontal and vertical.


I propose of starting with that ;)
 [1]: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To centralise the content, what you're looking to do is apply the following to `body` and `.wrap_content` (and also possibly also `.wrap_site`):

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
```

And the following to **purely** `body`:

```
height: 100vh;
```

This results in the following:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var languages = ["¡Hola, me llamo x! Bienvenido a mi página web.", "Привет, меня зовут x. Добро пожаловать на мой сайт.", "Hallo, ich heiße x. Willkommen auf meiner Webseite.", "你好, 我叫 x。欢迎来到我的网站。"];
  var counter = 0;
  var $exc = $('#translate')
  setInterval(function() {
    $exc.text(languages[counter++]);
    if (counter >= languages.length) {
      counter = 0;
    }
  }, 2500)
})
```

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


/********** LANDINGPAGE.CSS **********/


/**********  **********/

*,
header,
footer {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1vw;
  color: #4c4c4c;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 4vw;
}


/********** SITE **********/

.wrap_site {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 5%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrap_content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.button {
  border: 1px solid #4c4c4c;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1vw;
  padding: 8px 18px;
  background-color: white;
}

.button:hover {
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
  color: white;
  background-color: #4c4c4c;
}


/********** HEADER **********/

.wrap_header {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #4c4c4c;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/********** FOOTER **********/

.wrap_footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 5%;
  border-top: 1px solid #4c4c4c;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrap_site">
    <div class="wrap_header">
      <header>
        <p></p>
        <!-- filler -->
        <p>This website is currently under construction.</p>
      </header>
    </div>

    <main class="wrap_content">
      <h1>Hi, my name is x. Welcome to my website.</h1>
      <h2 id="translate">你好, 我叫 x。欢迎来到我的网站。</h2>
      <br />
      <h2><a href="#" class="button">ABOUT ME</a></h2>
    </main>

    <div class="wrap_footer">
      <footer>
        <a href="mailto:x">contact@x.com  </a>
        <a href="imprint">⚖️ Imprint</a> </footer>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Also, note that you are declaring jQuery **outside** of your HTML in your example (in addition to loading it in the `<body>`). I assume this double-up is just due to including a Stack Snippet, but note that jQuery should be loaded from inside your `<head>` section, and only included **once**.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Chcek my solution:

https://codepen.io/Czeran/pen/OjpKoj?editors=1100

I used display: flex on body element and added to header position: absolute;

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 5%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a height and use [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction):

```
.wrap_site {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

**JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/435xvrm0/2/**